# Regex to properly match urls with a particular domain and also if there is a subdomain added

Tags: regex, url, subdomain

I have the following regex:

```
(^|^[^:]+:\/\/|[^\.]+\.)hello\.net
```

Which seems to work fors most cases such as these:

```
http://hello.net
https://hello.net
http://www.hello.net
https://www.hello.net
http://domain.hello.net
https://solutions.hello.net
hello.net
www.hello.net
```

However it still matches this which it should not:

```
hello.net.domain.com
```

You can see it here:
https://regex101.com/r/fBH112/1

I am basically trying to check if a url is part of `hello.net`. so `hello.net` and any subdomains such as `sub.hello.net` should all match.
it should also match `hello.net/bye`. So anything after hello.net is irrelevant.

Comment: You forgot to "close" the pattern with `$` to make it match the whole string

Comment: ah sorry, let me update the question, whatever comes after hello.net should not matter. e.g. hello.net/bye

Comment: Ok then use `(^|^[^:]+:\/\/|[^.]+\.)hello\.net(?:\/.*)?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/taA9rx/1

Comment: Maybe `^(?:\w+:\/\/)?(?:[^\/.]+\.)?hello\.net(?:\/.*)?$` will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix your pattern by adding `(?:\/.*)?$` at the end:

```
(^|^[^:]+:\/\/|[^.]+\.)hello\.net(?:\/.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/taA9rx/1). The `(?:\/.*)?$` matches an optional sequence of `/` and any 0 or more chars and then the end of string.

You might consider a "cleaner" pattern like

```
^(?:\w+:\/\/)?(?:[^\/.]+\.)?hello\.net(?:\/.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/taA9rx/2). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\w+:\/\/)?` - an optional occurrence of 1+ word chars, and then `://` char sqequence
- `(?:[^\/.]+\.)?` - an optional occurrence of any 1 or more chars other than `/` and `.` and then `.`
- `hello\.net` - `hello.net`
- `(?:\/.*)?$` - an optional occurrence of `/` and then any 0+ chars and then end of string